# Delete rows if cell contains certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I want to perform this functions in this order:
1. Activate auto-filter function
2. In column M, tick 'deposit reversed' and 'blank'
3. Delete entire rows for cell that contain 'AQ*', 'AI*', 'BG' in column C. (NOTE: * represents numbers after the alphabets)

I have tried macro recording using Auto Filter but it only delete rows up to a specified range (which may differ if I use other set of data). VBA as per below.

Is there any EASIER/BETTER way to perform this?

Appreciate your help!

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
Rows("1:1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$46437").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:= _
    "=Deposit Reversed", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$46437").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "AQ", "AQ01E166N", "AQ01E294N", "AQ01E316N", "AQ01E373N"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$46017").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "AI", "AI04_MMRASHI_TWT", "AI04E230N", "AI04E269N", "AI04E323N"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
Rows("10236:10236").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$45998").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "BG", "BG01A004", "BG01H082", "BG01H106N"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
Rows("5:5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be BG* or just BG?

Comment: BG(continued by numbers - hence, I used *). Same goes to other search criteria

Comment: @Jeeped: It may be easier if I use excel formula first in column A (ie=LEFT(C2,2). If this is the case, what is the best VBA for the whole process? 

Search criteria: AQ, AI, BG

Comment: perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would give you more feedback

Answer (score 1):

Put the wildcarded filter criteria into an array and cycle through them. You won't find a faster method of removing the rows and it is safe as long as you check for the existence of rows to delete before deleting them.

```
    Dim c As Long, vCRITC As Variant
    vCRITC = Array("AQ*", "AI*", "BG*")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With Sheets("Sheet7").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        If .AutoFilter Then .AutoFilter
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count, Columns("A:N").Count)
            .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=Deposit Reversed", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
            For c = LBound(vCRITC) To UBound(vCRITC)
                .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Chr(61) & vCRITC(c)
                With .Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(3))) Then _
                        .Rows.Delete
                End With
                .AutoFilter Field:=3
            Next c
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It seems there was a typo in your original question that did not include the asterisk wildcard for *BG*. That may have to do with the composition editor using asterisks to note italics. This first sets the criteria on column M then adds (and removes) each wildcard criteria to column C, deleting rows that it finds.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. It shows error - code execution has been interrupted - at the 1st `End With` when I ran the macro

Comment: You probably don't have a *Sheet7*. I try to stay away from *ActiveSheet* but should have noted that you needed to change the name of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

it is not required to use autofilter for such purposes

use this

```
Sub test()
Dim i&
i = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
With ActiveSheet
    While i <> 1
        If .Cells(i, "M").Value = "deposit reversed" Or .Cells(i, "M").Value = "" Then
            If UCase(.Cells(i, "C").Value) Like "AQ*" Or _
                UCase(.Cells(i, "C").Value) Like "AI*" Or _
                 UCase(.Cells(i, "C").Value) Like "BG*" Then
                 .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        End If
        i = i - 1
    Wend
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It is a somewhat canonical practise to work from the bottom up (or right-to-left) when deleting rows or columns. This avoids conflicts when the cell you are currently on is removed and you are shifted to another cell before the loop cycles.

Comment: From [How to delete cells by using a "For Each...Next" loop](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/291300) - *"When Microsoft Excel deletes row 3, all cells move up one row. For example, cell A3 assumes the contents of cell A4, cell A4 assumes the contents of cell A5, and so forth. After the For Each...Next loop evaluates a cell, it evaluates the next cell; therefore, when cells are shifted, they may be skipped by the loop."*